# What is the best way to Importing a list from a python function into tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the below python script that is running and returning some lists:

How I can trigger an action in the GUI (the second code) using the output of the python script(the first code) is there a general way to do that

I'm using Pycharm as a code editor and I run the scripts using Pycharm builtin functions

```
import cv2
import time
import os
import HandTrackingModule as htm


def fcf():

wCam, hCam = 640, 480

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, wCam)
cap.set(4, hCam)

folderPath = "FingerImages"
myList = os.listdir(folderPath)
#print(myList)
overlayList = []
for imPath in myList:
    image = cv2.imread(f'{folderPath}/{imPath}')
    # print(f'{folderPath}/{imPath}')
    overlayList.append(image)

#print(len(overlayList))
pTime = 0

detector = htm.handDetector(detectionCon=0.75)

tipIds = [4, 8, 12, 16, 20]

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    img = detector.findHands(img)
    lmList = detector.findPosition(img, draw=False)
    ts = time.time()
    #print(lmList)


    if len(lmList) != 0:
        fingers = []
        satisfied = []
        neutral = []
        unsatisfied = []
        # Thumb
        if lmList[tipIds[0]][1] > lmList[tipIds[0] - 1][1]:
            fingers.append(1)
        else:
            fingers.append(0)

        # 4 Fingers
        for id in range(1, 5):
            if lmList[tipIds[id]][2] < lmList[tipIds[id] - 2][2]:
                fingers.append(1)
            else:
                fingers.append(0)

        #print(fingers)
        totalFingers = fingers.count(1)
        #print(totalFingers)

       


        #h, w, c = overlayList[totalFingers - 1].shape
        #img[0:h, 0:w] = overlayList[totalFingers - 1]

        #cv2.rectangle(img, (20, 225), (170, 425), (0, 255, 0), cv2.FILLED)
        #cv2.putText(img, str(totalFingers), (45, 375), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
#                    10, (255, 0, 0), 25)


    cTime = time.time()
    fps = 1 / (cTime - pTime)
    pTime = cTime

    cv2.putText(img, f'FPS: {int(fps)}', (400, 70), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                3, (255, 0, 0), 3)

    cv2.imshow("Image", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

if __name__=='main':
    fcf()
```

and I have the below tkinter GUI:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
from FingerCounter import *

root = Tk()

root.title('Customer Satisfaction Survey')
screen_width = root.winfo_screenwidth()
screen_height = root.winfo_screenheight()
#root.geometry(f'{screen_width}x{screen_height}')
root.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
root.columnconfigure(2, weight=1)

#root.attributes('-fullscreen',True)

frame = Frame(root)
# Define the images
Img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("coo.png"))
Img1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("Doo.png"))
Img2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage( Image.open("Wave.png"))
#
ImgLabel00 = Label(root, text="   \n \n \n \n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n \n \n \n \n  ")
ImgLabel00.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
ImgLabel = Label(image=Img)
ImgLabel.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)
ImgLabel1 = Label(image=Img1)
ImgLabel1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5)
ImgLabel2 =  Label(image=Img2)
ImgLabel2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5)

# craeting a label widget
myLabel = Label(root, text="      ", font=("Arial", 35))
#myLabel1 = Label(root, text="      ")
myLabel2 = Label(root, text="      ", font=("Arial", 35))
#myLabel3 = Label(root, text="      ")
myLabel4 = Label(root, text="     ", font=("Arial", 35))
#shoving it into the screen
myLabel.grid(row=2, column=0)
#myLabel1.grid(row=0, column=2)
myLabel2.grid(row=2, column=1)
#myLabel3.grid(row=0, column=6)
myLabel4.grid(row=2, column=2)




root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please explain what you exactly want to trigger and when

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my approach is optimum but this is how I worked it:

I adopted multithreading and created two threads one that is running the Tkinter GUI and the second thread runs the python script.

The python script writes the output of one function to a text file while the GUI on the first thread reads the same text file and triggers the action.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Could you expand on this by providing e.g. code to demonstrate what you're talking about? It's excellent to offer an explanation, but having a combination of an explanation _and_ code is really useful for future readers.